If $A$ is closed in $X$, then is the Bochner space $L^p(\mathbb R, A)$ closed in $L^p(\mathbb R, X)$?
Let $X$ be a Banach space on $\mathbb C$ and $A$ be a closed subspace of $X$. (Automatically, $A$ is also Banach.) And suppose $p\in(1,\infty).$ Then, can we say that $L^p(\mathbb R, A)$ is closed in $L^p(\mathbb R, X)$ ?
So let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence in $L^p(\mathbb R, A)$ and $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R,X).$ Then, I want to know whether $f\in L^p(\mathbb R, A)$ or not.
Of course $\int |f|^p<\infty$ is O.K. but I don't know how to see whether or not $f(x)\in A$ for all $x\in\mathbb R.$ Any idea ?

For this question, it is important that you explain what you mean by $L^p(\mathbb R,X)$ and $L^p(\mathbb R,A)$. Are they spaces of functions or quotients of spaces of functions? The answer provided by Evangelopoulos Foivos is written with quotients in mind, but you writing "$f(x)\in A$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$" in your question and "$f(t)\in A$ for all $t$" in your comment suggests that you actually want to talk about functions and not their equivalence classes…

Hint:
If $f_n \to f $ in $L^p(\mathbb R, X)$ then there exists a subsequence $(k_n)$ such that  $\|f_{k_n}(t) - f(t)\|_X \to 0$  for almost all $t \in \mathbb R$.

Then, for a.e. $t$, one has $f(t)\in A$ by ${f_{k_n}(t)}_n\subset A$ and closedness of $A$. But can we say $f(t)\in A$ for all $t$ ?

Of course not. Usually when working with $L^p$ spaces you identify functions that are equal a.e.
